# how to avaid recycler from scrowing back to top

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i am beginner, i want to create post app, which has like and comment button, but when i click like button, the RecyclerView getting (scrolling) back to top. i want it tobe like facebook or twitter, when click like it pop up there and not goig to top

MainActivity

```
private void loadPosts() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            posts.clear();
           for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               ModelPost modelPost=dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelPost.class);
             posts.add(modelPost);
               adapterPosts=new AdapterPosts(getActivity(),posts);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPosts);

           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

myAdapter

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    final String uid=modelPosts.get(position).getUid();
    String nameh=modelPosts.get(position).getUname();
    final String titlee=modelPosts.get(position).getTitle();
    final String descri=modelPosts.get(position).getDescription();
    final String ptime=modelPosts.get(position).getPtime();
    String dp=modelPosts.get(position).getUdp();
    String plike=modelPosts.get(position).getPlike();
    final String image=modelPosts.get(position).getUimage();
    String email=modelPosts.get(position).getUemail();
    String comm=modelPosts.get(position).getPcomments();
    final String pid=modelPosts.get(position).getPid();
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(ptime));
    String timedate= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa",calendar).toString();
    holder.name.setText(nameh);
    holder.title.setText(titlee);
    holder.description.setText(descri);
    holder.time.setText(timedate);
    holder.like.setText(plike + " Likes");
    holder.comments.setText(comm + " Comments");
    setLikes(holder,ptime);
    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(dp).into(holder.picture);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if(image.equals("noImage")){

        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(holder.image);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
    holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showMoreOptions(holder.more,uid, myuid,ptime,image);
        }
    });
    holder.likebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final int plike=Integer.parseInt(modelPosts.get(position).getPlike());
            mprocesslike=true;
            final String postid=modelPosts.get(position).getPtime();
            liekeref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(mprocesslike){
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(postid).hasChild(myuid)){
                            postref.child(postid).child("plike").setValue(""+(plike-1));
                            liekeref.child(postid).child(myuid).removeValue();
                            mprocesslike=false;
                        }
                        else {
                            postref.child(postid).child("plike").setValue(""+(plike+1));
                            liekeref.child(postid).child(myuid).setValue("Liked");
                            mprocesslike=false;
                            addToHisNotification(""+uid,""+postid,"Liked Your Post");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, PostDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pid",ptime);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable=(BitmapDrawable)holder.image.getDrawable();
            if(bitmapDrawable==null){
                shareTextOnly(titlee,descri);
            }
            else {
                Bitmap bitmap=bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                shareImageandText(titlee,descri,bitmap);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, ThereProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, PostLikedByActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pid",ptime);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
private void shareTextOnly(String titlee, String descri) {

    String sharebody= titlee + "\n" + descri;
    Intent intentt=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentt.setType("text/plain");
    intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject Here");
    intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sharebody);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentt,"Share Via"));
}

private void shareImageandText(String titlee, String descri, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Uri uri=saveImageToShare(bitmap);
    String sharebody= titlee + "\n" + descri;
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sharebody);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject Here");
    intent.setType("image/png");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share Via"));
}

private Uri saveImageToShare(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagefolder=new File(context.getCacheDir(),"images");
    Uri uri=null;
    try {
        imagefolder.mkdirs();
        File file=new File(imagefolder,"shared_image.png");
        FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.xzuma99.askpedia.fileprovider",file);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(context,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return uri;
}

private void addToHisNotification(String hisUid,String pid,String notification){
    String timestamp=""+System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<Object,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("pid",pid);
    hashMap.put("timestamp",timestamp);
    hashMap.put("puid",hisUid);
    hashMap.put("notification",notification);
    hashMap.put("suid",myuid);
    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.child(hisUid).child("Notifications").child(timestamp).setValue(hashMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });

}
private void setLikes(final MyHolder holder,final String pid) {
    liekeref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.child(pid).hasChild(myuid)){
                holder.likebtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_star_liked,0,0,0);
                holder.likebtn.setText("Liked");
            }
            else {
                holder.likebtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_star_like,0,0,0);
                holder.likebtn.setText("Like");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void showMoreOptions(ImageButton more, String uid, String myuid, final String pid, final String image) {

    PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context,more, Gravity.END);
    if(uid.equals(myuid)){
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"Delete");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,1,0,"Edit");
    }
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,2,0,"View Post");
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId()==0){
                beginDelete(pid,image);
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()==1){
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, AddPostActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key","editpost");
                intent.putExtra("editpostId",pid);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()==2){
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, PostDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("pid",pid);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}

private void beginDelete(String pid, String image) {

    if(image.equals("noImage")){
        deleteWithoutImage(pid);
        deletelike(pid);
    }
    else {
        deltewithImage(pid,image);
        deletelike(pid);
    }
}

private void deletelike(String pid) {
    Query query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Likes").child(pid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Deleted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void deltewithImage(final String pid, String image) {
    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setMessage("Deleting");
    StorageReference picref= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(image);
    picref.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Query query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("ptime").equalTo(pid);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                      dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
                  }

                  pd.dismiss();
                  Toast.makeText(context,"Deleted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}


private void deleteWithoutImage(String pid) {
    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setMessage("Deleting");
    Query query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("ptime").equalTo(pid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
            }
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Deleted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelPosts.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView picture,image;
    TextView name,time,title,description,like,comments;
    ImageButton more;
    Button likebtn,comment,share;
    LinearLayout profile;
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);



        picture=itemView.findViewById(R.id.picturetv);
        image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pimagetv);
        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.unametv);
        time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.utimetv);
        more=itemView.findViewById(R.id.morebtn);
        title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ptitletv);
        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.descript);
        like=itemView.findViewById(R.id.plikeb);
        comments=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pcommentco);
        likebtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        comment=itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        share=itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        profile=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilelayout);
    }
}
```

}

which has like and comment button, but when i click like button, the RecyclerView getting (scrolling) back to top. i want it tobe like facebook or twitter, when click like it pop up there and not goig to top

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take two approaches to get this working.

1. do not repopulate the recycler view on the button being clicked.

Use the method
`yourRecyclerViewName.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);` for getting the reference of the particular view you want to change the like symbol of. And then change it's properties .

2. repopulate but save the scrollposition of the like button so that it moves to that location automatically.
   use  `yourRecyclerViewName.scrollToPosition(pos);`

[how to scroll to position StackOverflow answer](http://yourRecyclerViewName.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);)

Comment: it work, thnks a lot